# An application of Fenchel-Rockafellar theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I have trouble understanding an application of the Fenchel-Rockafellar theorem in the book *''Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations''* by Haim Brezis. The theorem is stated below.

> **Theorem (Fenchel-Rockafellar).** Let $\varphi,\psi:E\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ be two convex functions. Assume that there is some
>   $x_0\in D(\varphi)\cap D(\psi)$ such that $\varphi$ is continuous at
>   $x_0$, where $D(\varphi)=\{x\in E\mid\varphi(x)\neq+\infty\}$ and
>   likewise for $D(\psi)$. Then \begin{align*} \inf_{x\in
>  E}\{\varphi(x)+\psi(x)\} &=  \sup_{f\in
>  E^*}\{-\varphi^*(-f)-\psi^*(f)\} \\ &= \max_{f\in
>  E^*}\{-\varphi^*(-f)-\psi^*(f)\} \\ &= -\min_{f\in
>  E^*}\{\varphi^*(-f)+\psi^*(f)\} \end{align*}

To provide some background, the conjugate function $\varphi^*$ of $\varphi$ is defined below

> **Definition.** Let $\varphi:E\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ be a function such that $\varphi\not\equiv +\infty$ (i.e.,
>   $D(\varphi)\neq\varnothing$). We define the *conjugate function*
>   $\varphi^*:E^*\to (-\infty,+\infty]$ to be \begin{equation}
>  \varphi^*(f) = \sup_{x\in E}  \{\langle f,x \rangle - \varphi(x) \}
>  \quad (f\in E^*). \end{equation}

And here is the example.

> *Example.* Let $K$ be a nonempty convex set in $E$. We claim that for every $x_0\in E$ we have  \begin{equation} \mathrm{dist}(x_0,K) = 
>  \inf_{x\in K}\Vert x-x_0\Vert
> = \max_{f\in E^* \\ \Vert f \Vert\leq 1}  \{ \langle f,x_0\rangle - I_K^*(f)\}. \end{equation} Indeed, we have  \begin{equation*}
> \inf_{x\in K}\Vert x-x_0 \Vert =  \inf_{x\in E}\{\varphi(x)+\psi(x)\},
>  \end{equation*} with $\varphi(x)=\Vert x-x_0 \Vert$ and 
>   \begin{equation} \psi(x)=I_K(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & x\in K, \\
> +\infty & x\notin K. \end{cases} \end{equation}  Applying the Fenchel-Rockafellar theorem, then the first equation in this example
>   can be obtained.

I understand that the theorem immediate gives
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in E}\{\varphi(x)+\psi(x)\} = 
\max_{f\in E^*}\{-\varphi^*(-f)-\psi^*(f)\}
\end{equation}
which is
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in E}\{\Vert x-x_0 \Vert + I_K(x)\} = 
\max_{f\in E^*}\{-\varphi^*(-f)-I_k^*(f)\}.
\end{equation}
To take the infimum, $I_K(x)$ on the left hand side cannot be $+\infty$. Hence $x$ must be restricted to $K$, where $I_K(x)=0$. Thus,
\begin{equation}
\inf_{x\in K}\Vert x-x_0 \Vert = 
\max_{f\in E^*}\{-\varphi^*(-f)-I_k^*(f)\}.
\end{equation}
However, I am unable to proceed any further. By similar reasoning I can also show that
\begin{equation}
\psi^*(f) = I_K^*(f) = \sup_{x\in K}\langle f,x \rangle,
\end{equation}
but it doesn't seem to be of much use.

I think I mostly have two questions concerning the statement

> \begin{equation} \mathrm{dist}(x_0,K) =  \inf_{x\in K}\Vert x-x_0\Vert
>  = \max_{f\in E^* \\ \Vert f \Vert\leq 1}  \{  \langle f,x_0\rangle - I_K^*(f)\}. \end{equation}

1. Why is there the restriction of $f$ to $\Vert f \Vert\leq 1$?
2. How does the term $\langle f, x_0\rangle$ arise?

I appreciate it if anyone can help me out with these questions.

Comment: One useful lemma is that the conjugate of a norm is the indicator function for the dual norm unit ball. It's also helpful to derive a formula for the conjugate of $f(x-x_0)$ in terms of the conjugate of $f$.